# sizeof for a character array

Tags: c, arrays, character, sizeof

why do I get results 6, and then 8 by from the following code? I searched through the posts but cannot find an exact match of my question. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getSize(const char *str)
{
        printf("%d\n", sizeof(str)/sizeof(char));
}

int main()
{
        char str[]="hello";
        printf("%d\n", sizeof(str)/sizeof(char));
        getSize(str);
}
```

Comment: You probably know this, but just in case-- use `strlen(str)` if what you wanted was the length of the string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the sizeof( a pointer pointing to an array )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeof-a-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

Comment: @mark4o yes I knew that, but want to figure the above out.

Comment: @Bo Persson Thanks for pointing that out. Now I realize that mine is a similar one :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `getSize()` function, `str` is a pointer. Therefore `sizeof(str)` returns the **size of a pointer**. (which is 8 bytes in this case)

In your `main()` function, `str` is an array. Therefore `sizeof(str)` returns the **size of the array**.

This is one of the subtle differences between arrays and pointers.

Comment: I wouldn't really call it subtle: *Hey guys when I call `sizeof` on different types I get different results?!*

Comment: @todda.speot.is It would have been subtle if the OP had written `void getSize(const char str[])`.

Comment: @Complicatedseebio That's starting to depart from subtle differences between arrays/pointers and moving towards subtle differences between arrays/arrays...

Answer (score 2):

Different types, different sizes.

In `main`, `str` is a `char[6]`. In `getSize` `str` is a `const char *`. A pointer is (on a 64-bit platform) 8-bytes, so (given that `sizeof(char) = 1`):

```
6/1 = 6
8/1 = 8
```

Comment: I see. I think I knew that when passing an array to a function, the array is converted into a pointer pointing to the first element. But I just found it strange why its size is 8 bytes. Apparently I forgot the system is a 64-bit one.